# AWS DynamoDB DocumentClient query error - One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, documentclient

I have an AWS DynamoDb table called `AccountXX` which stores items with a JSON structure as:

```
{
  "id": "some id value", // also the partition key for the table
  "name": "a name",
  "email": "an email address",
  "salt": [12, 3, ... ], // an array of random values
  "hash": [1, 5, ... ],  // an array representing a hashed password
  ... // and some more attributes
}
```

There is a Global Secondary Index named `Account_email_hash_salt_gsi` on the `AccountXX` table which has the partition key email and has the additional attributes `hash, salt` and `id`.

When I issue the following AWS CLI command, I am able to query an item in the table successfully:

```
aws dynamodb query --table AccountXX 
  --index-name Account_email_hash_salt_gsi 
  --key-condition-expression "email = :emailValue" 
  --expression-attribute-values file://values.json
```

The contents of `values.json` is:

```
{":emailValue":{"S": "someone@somewhere.in"}}
```

However, when I issue an analogous call using `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` instance using the following parameter object, I get an error:

```
  const params = {
    TableName: accountTable,       // will be set to 'AccountXX'
    IndexName: "Account_email_hash_salt_gsi",
    KeyConditionExpression:"#email = :emailValue",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#email": "email"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":emailValue": {"S": loginToken.email}
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false
  };
```

The error I get is:

```
ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

I also tried using a modified parameter object as follows:

```
  const params = {
    TableName: accountTable,   // will be set to 'AccountXX'
    IndexName: "Account_email_hash_salt_gsi",
    KeyConditionExpression:"#email = :emailValue",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#email": "email"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":emailValue": loginToken.email   // directly using string type
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false
  };
```

In this case, I got the following error:

```
ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

In both cases, my DynamoDB DocumentClient query is issued as:

```
const data = await dynamo.query(params).promise();
```

What should I do to fix the `params` object so that I am able to query the table successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found and fixed the problem. The issue was not with the DynamoDB query or parameters construct. **The root cause was the problem with the Lambda passing the POST request body and the handler incorrectly handling it.** The handler was missing a `JSON.parse(event.body)` and hence `loginToken` was a string. Therefore `loginToken.email` was evaluating to empty causing the query to fail.

BTW, I found [Amazon NoSQL Workbench tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html) that was mentioned in [an answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64990550/11256164) to be very helpful in exploring queries and autogenerating them using the UI. I used that to ensure that the query parameters were syntactically correct and then was able to find the root cause after some troubleshooting.